# WearOS app rejected because of "show scrollbars"

Tags: google-play, wear-os, google-play-console, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-3.0

I have a WearOS app published since years but since a few weeks updates get rejected with the helpful message "show the scrollbar" and [link](https://notifications.google.com/g/p/ANiao5otlYbj-dzsnlqSZpkWfI-S42bBO8sqcuL8mawrdnckx1jQ7oXQi4toHG2_liCKyF8qmN3sW-uE8FErIhc0GjJtdUUDCMcuGfXRnl861YKxMSrQDV--rlpsm_3rrMk952tpZX_aX1oNOvR27Pjol93gX28TMZCZv8Hu6U3xPlzq5wfS7-4YscmUXjW9hbYTXzdFQL-_6p4KdnQYw80lUiKKAkGGLb0fcrPKmA_BQstGHwYBVBYSIHj9n68RQk0Svo_V0-JD). For the best of my knowledge, and I checked multiple times now, every single screen in the app has scrollbars. I even modified the `PositionIndicator` from Compose to show when you open the screens, normally it only becomes visible when you scroll.

Is there anything I can do? I already appealed the decision with now success.

Comment: A possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355093/11632959

Comment: Haha, asked the same day. Seems to be similar to my issue and I also thought this could be the case but I made sure to add enough items in the lists of the demo account that everything can scroll. I got my app now accepted after modifying the PositionIndicator, will post a solution