# How to handle unsubstantiated app rejection from Google?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, scrollbar, wear-os

My Android app has a companion Wear OS app. The companion app's main UI is a scrollable view with a `PositionIndicator` that (per the design guidelines) shows up while the view is scrolling.

The `PositionIndicator` is plainly visible (see screenshot), yet Google rejected an update to the Android app, claiming that the (unchanged) companion app did not show scrollbars. Just in case, I updated the companion app to change the scrollbar to orange (from green) to make for greater contrast. That made no difference - Google still claims there is no scrollbar.

The original rejection contained no information whatsoever to support the claim of missing scrollbars - no screenshot, no verbal description (aside from the raw assertion) and no information on what device/emulator the alleged problem was observed on. For that reason, I appealed both rejections, noting all of that. Google's response to the appeals was useless - a straight copy of the original unsubstantiated assertion.

Does anybody have any advice on how to move forward with this? As it is, it is impossible for me to do anything, since there is no evidence of the problem, and the assertion of the problem is plainly contradicted by appearance and behavior of the app itself.[image: Scrollbars screenshot]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77352594/5513788

Comment: Yes - at least I hope so. I found that discussion right after I asked my question. I'm assuming the issue is with bezel rotation not showing the scrollbars, and I've implemented the suggested change. We'll see what happens. 

I wish Google would provide sufficient information to reproduce the problem. In no case of a rejection was there ever sufficient information to reproduce.

Comment: They should include a screenshot in any new rejections. Consider dropping into the compose-wear Slack channel on kotlinlang.slack.com if it continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodePoet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5513788/code-poet) provided a link to a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77352594/5513788) that led to the solution. In that discussion was a suggestion to ensure that bezel initiated scrolling caused the PositionIndicator to display. When added the one line change suggested there, my app was approved.

Note - that might be unrelated however, because the last time I updated the Wear OS app, all I did was adjust the list item layout to better handle user font size changes - I didn't do anything about the PositionIndicator, and the change was approved. I suspect that their testing software isn't very reliable.

Comment: You should mark this as the solution

Comment: I will. The site won't let me do it until tomorrow. ;-)

Comment: Oh, didn't know there was a limit on that 

Comment: I think it only applies if you answer your own question. Right now it tells me "You can accept your own answer in 3 hours".

Answer (score 1):

I think the google knows this issue, but now it seems still alpha status.

Wear compose 1.4.0-alpha01 :
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/wear-compose#1.4.0-alpha01

> PositionIndicator is now shown by default when a screen is first displayed.  This change was introduced in order to help meet Wear Quality guidelines. Unfortunately, it means that screenshot tests will need to be updated on screens that include PositionIndicator, as the PositionIndicator would not previously have been displayed. (419cef7)